# How do I set the jmx to listen in a specific IP

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am trying to configure jboss to allow monitoring with a jmx tool (I am looking at a few so no need to give).

Looking at the properties in [java jmx docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html) it does not seem to have a property to set the host, so if I run more than one jboss in the same machine then I have to define the different ports in each of the startups scripts (which is a maintenance nightmare)

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port
com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate
com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file
com.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file
com.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config
```

Does anyone know how can I setup the host in the jmx?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you cannot(unless you start modifying things in your container).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331615/how-to-have-jmx-bind-to-a-specific-interface